# How to control if someone is sending empty string to the decimal value?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a web service function which has a decimal value i.e. BRGEW.

Client is supposed to send the decimal value but he's sending string from SOAP UI and it's failing in conversion.

I have done this to control it but doesn't work.

```
if (General.BRGEW == 0 || General.BRGEW.ToString() == "") {
  General.BRGEW =0;
}
```

How can I control this?

Comment: How does it 'not work'? Does it fail?
If so, I believe changing the IF sentence to ask for the empty string _first_ will do the trick.

Comment: What's wrong with `double.TryParse`?

Comment: My first rule is of string, is to never store, transmit or rerieve something as string. string is easily the 2nd worst format for automation, only raw bytes are worse. My second rule is that if you can not do that, at least try to pick the same encoding and culture format on both ends. | The existing WebService Classes and Patterns do tend to take care of those details. And often also of parsing the string back into something usefull, like a number. Try those befoer you try to reinvent the wheel. But if you got to do this manually, TryParse() is the droid you should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need **String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)** method

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to check that user input is decimal or not

```
var check= double.IsNaN(variable); //It will return boolean value after that add your code logic
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the value is null or empty, if it is not null or empty then convert it.

```
decimal number;
string value = "";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{

  if(Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (General.BRGEW == 0)
{
    General.BRGEW = 0;
}
```

doesn't change things much :) If `RRGEW` is already 0, then setting it to zero will have little effect.

---

## A. Make the client send the number

This would be the easiest solution.

## B. Deal with it

If you cannot make the client send the number then the following could help:

1. Make `General.BRGEW` as string.
2. Create another property e.g. `General.BRGEWAsInt`

```
public class X {
    public string BRGEW {get; set;}
    public int BRGEWAsInt => Int32.TryParse(BRGEW, out var number)
         ? number
         : 0;
  }
```

*You don't need to make a property, you could just parse when you need.*